# How to format a text excerpt in Latex?

Tags: formatting

I'm using Overleaf to quote a paragraph as an excerpt in my paper. It's just several short sentences. Currently, I'm using

```
\begin{quote}   
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.    
\end{quote}
```

However, it does not contain a caption. I want to make it something like this image (with a caption, and the excerpt using a different font from the main text). [image]

I'm new to Latex. How can I create this kind of excerpt?

Comment: Welcome! By “caption” are you meaning the “Excerpt 12” label, with automatic numbering?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. "Excerpt 12" together with the following texts.

Comment: Do you want to re-create the text for the excerpt, or do you want to include a screenshot instead?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to use `\newtheorem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{excerpt}{Excerpt}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.    

\begin{excerpt}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.    
\end{excerpt}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.    

\begin{excerpt}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.    
\end{excerpt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Further customization is possible.